# How to combine two Ruby collections?

Tags: ruby

A user is given two inputs, `A` and `B` (collections), and a number, `X`, and must create an output. The output starts with the first value from `A`, then takes `X` units from `B`, then the second value of `A`, and continuing like that until both `A` and `B` have been exhausted. You can assume `1 < X < sizeof(B)`. However, if either `A` or `B` runs out, you should loop back to the beginning of the short collection, and continue until the other runs out. The looping back should continue until both collections have hit their end.

What is an *elegant* way to do this in Ruby? I have some half-broken code and can't seem to find a good way to do this. No, it's not a homework problem. I have strange hobbies.

Here's some sample tests of the behavior I want:

```
# SomeModule.copy(A, B, X)
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1 a2 a3),    %w(b1 b2 b3),       1) == %w(a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3))
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1),          %w(b1),             1) == %w(a1 b1))
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1),          %w(b1 b2 b3),       1) == %w(a1 b1 a1 b2 a1 b3))
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1 a2),       %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 2) == %w(a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 b4 a1 b5 b1))
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1 a2),       %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 2) == %w(a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 b4 a1 b5 b1))
SomeModule.copy(%w(a1 a2 a3 a4), %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 3) == %w(a1 b1 b2 b3 a2 b4 b5 b1 a3 b2 b3 b4 a4 b5 b1 b2))
```

Comment: What's the way you tried in Ruby? Even half-broken, totally hopeless code is a sign you've invested effort in your solution, and it motivates people to help.

Comment: A simple example that includes your desired result would be helpful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I included sample tests with input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something, the idea is to iterate every array until both of them reach their max index:

```
def custom_combine(a,b,x)
  max_index_a = a.count - 1
  max_index_b = b.count - 1
  a_run_out = false
  b_run_out = false

  output = []

  a.cycle.each_with_index do |elem_a, index_a|
    output << elem_a
    # base on a index get x elements from b
    x.times do |i|
      index_b = ((index_a * x) + i) % (max_index_b + 1)
      output << b[index_b]
      b_run_out = true if index_b == max_index_b
    end
    a_run_out = true if index_a == max_index_a
    break if a_run_out && b_run_out
  end

  output
end

a = %w(a1 a2 a3 a4)
b = %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5)
x = 3

custom_combine(a,b,x)
# => ["a1", "b1", "b2", "b3", "a2", "b4", "b5", "b1", "a3", "b2", "b3", "b4", "a4", "b5", "b1", "b2"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had read through enumerable and I guess I skipped over `cycle`, or failed to understand exactly what it did. That's a nice way to do it.

Comment: What I finally came up with was pretty similar to what you have here, with the collection tracking logic pulled out into a class.

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable` has an `each_slice` method that'll let you iterate over an enumerable object N items at a time. Using it, you can do something like this:

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
a2 = [10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32, 40, 41, 42, 50, 51, 52, 60] 

a1.each_slice(1).zip(a2.each_slice(3)).flatten

# => [1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 20, 21, 22, 3, 30, 31, 32, 4, 40, 41, 42, 5, 50, 51, 52, 6, 60]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what finally jumped out of my brain at 4.30am:

```
class InfiniteArray
  private
  attr_reader :collection
  attr_accessor :index, :wrapped_count
  public

  def initialize(collection)
    @collection = collection
    reset
  end

  def next
    value = collection[index]
    if index < collection.length - 1
      self.index = index + 1
    else
      self.index = 0
      self.wrapped_count = wrapped_count + 1
    end
    value
  end

  def wrapped?
    wrapped_count > 0
  end

  def reset
    @index = 0
    @wrapped_count = 0
  end
end

class IntervalCopier
  private
  attr_reader :source_collection, :destination_collection, :interval
  public

  def initialize(source_collection, destination_collection, interval)
    @source_collection = InfiniteArray.new(source_collection)
    @destination_collection = InfiniteArray.new(destination_collection)
    @interval = interval
  end

  def copy
    final = []
    until source_collection.wrapped? && destination_collection.wrapped? do
      final << source_collection.next
      interval.times { final << destination_collection.next }
    end
    [source_collection, destination_collection].each(&:reset)
    final
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def copy(array1, array2, slice_length)
  iterations = [array1.length,
                (array2.length.to_f / slice_length.to_f).round
               ].max

  result = []
  enum1 = array1.cycle
  enum2 = array2.cycle

  iterations.times do
    result << enum1.next
    slice_length.times { result << enum2.next }
  end

  result
end

require 'minitest/autorun'

class TestCopy < Minitest::Test
  def test_copy
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3),                               copy(%w(a1 a2 a3),    %w(b1 b2 b3),       1))
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1),                                           copy(%w(a1),          %w(b1),             1))
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1 a1 b2 a1 b3),                               copy(%w(a1),          %w(b1 b2 b3),       1))
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 b4 a1 b5 b1),                      copy(%w(a1 a2),       %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 2))
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 b4 a1 b5 b1),                      copy(%w(a1 a2),       %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 2))
    assert_equal(%w(a1 b1 b2 b3 a2 b4 b5 b1 a3 b2 b3 b4 a4 b5 b1 b2), copy(%w(a1 a2 a3 a4), %w(b1 b2 b3 b4 b5), 3))
  end
end
```